# PowerBI paginated reports automation

Tags: powerbi

I need to deliver reports to the external users to their whatever emails they might have. If that is possible how would I provide a personalized report to every user? Do I need to have a list of users somewhere? Also I need to send reports to many users at once. Do I need to do Power Automate? I am just getting into it, can someone please point at a concrete example?

Thanks

Comment: Have you read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/consumer/paginated-reports-subscriptions in particular _Email subscriptions can be sent with either the currently selected or default parameters for your report. You may set different parameter values for each subscription you create for your report._ It seems that if every recipient needs different parameter values, you need to set those up manually in the subscription. How many people are receiving reports? You know auto emailed reports are usually doomed to be ignored.

Comment: But how is user's email can be used in the report itself to pull data specific to that user?

Comment: I've never used subscriptions before but I guess you set up a subscription per email and put in the required parameter values for that email. That's why I asked how many emails. How do you split data by user in the current report? You must have an email input parameter right?

Comment: Well, it might be many. Although to get started using an email address as a report parameter can be a good idea.